# addChild(Button) in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am writing a class that extends mx.core.UIComponent.  In the constructor of this class, I would like to add a Button (spark.components.Button).  However, creating a new Button object (such as var b:Button = new Button();) and then doing this.addChild(b) doesn't work -- no button is appearing.  Is there any reason why a Button object can't be added as a child?

Edit: Just to add, when I print out the children, it says that the Button object is a child, but the Button doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `UIComponent` directly, you aren't getting the layout of the child handled for you; you would need to set the position and size of your child components manually ([see docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS460ee381960520ad-2811830c121e9107ecb-7ff9.html#WS460ee381960520ad-2811830c121e9107ecb-7ff1)).

Consider using a `Group` (or `Canvas`, if you're still on MX components) to handle child layout.  You can still add rendering in `updateDisplayList`, just make sure you call `super.updateDisplayList()` as well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the button in the createChildren method not in the constructor.

```
protected var button:Button;

override protected function createChildren():void {
    super.createChildren();

    button = new Button();

    addChild(button);
}
```

Depending on what you are trying to do you may also need to implement the measure and updateDisplayList methods.

Comment: Thanks -- this was useful but didn't end up working for me.  Even after implementing createChildren, measure, and updateDisplayList the button still wasn't appearing, not sure why.  But thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on the differences between ActionScript components and Flex components. When using a Flex component, you **must** use `container.addElement( element )`, not `container.addChild( child )`. As far as I am aware, the only classes with this functionality descend from `Group` (at least in the Spark framework, the one I am most familiar with). So extending UIComponent will not allow you to add a `Button`, although a UIComponent can be added to a Flex container (which I do not believe a normal Sprite can do)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  However, unless I am understanding [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf62b90-7fe9.html) wrong, I need to use addChild (not addElement) because the container I am adding to is an mx container, not a spark container.   The button doesn't appear whether I use an mx Button or a spark Button.  Both Button classes inherit from UIComponent and DisplayObject, so they should both be valid arguments for AddChild as far as I can tell...  Thanks again.